# How can I manually tell the system which USB device is a Bluetooth adapter?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, logitech, headset, bluez

I have purchased a Logitech h600 Headset and have read a few things about it. It uses Bluetooth, so I use it with my iPad, but to use it with my PC, I have to go into Windows (I HATE ANYTHING that has to do with booting Windows) and use Logitech's pairing tool in order to use my headset in Ubuntu again. This gets VERY annoying, and I know for sure that the USB adapter is Bluetooth, so I was wondering if I could somehow tell the system which USB port to try to get Bluetooth from, so that I could pair my headset without using Windows. Any answers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The H600 headset may use bluetooth but the pairing is coded into the dongle and appears only as a H600 audio headset, the dongle itself does not appear as bluetooth in any OS I have used.  With you pairing the headset to the iPad it must erase the pairing to the dongle and this is an undocumented feature as I have this headset and nothing about pairing without the dongle is mentioned in the guides.  The only fix I can think of is to ask logitech for the source code for the pairing tool used in windows and see if it can be compiled in Ubuntu or see if they will release a pairing tool for linux.

Comment: I doubt that Logitech will publish a Linux tool, it was only said to work on Windows and Mac. The source code might work, but I would have to figure out how. Anyway, Thanks you!